# Terraform how to associate an SSH Key or SSH username and password to azurerm_windows_virtual_machine

Tags: azure, ssh, terraform

I have multiple VM created and managed by terraform using azurerm_windows_virtual_machine, i don't find a way to associate ssh key or shh username and password to these VM and only i find this block

```
admin_ssh_key {
   username = "azureroot"
   public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}
}
```

that could be associated to a azurerm_linux_virtual_machine, but i use windows VM and not Linux VM

Comment: Windows do not use SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using username and password vm admin as a user of ssh key ;)